# How to change the default HTML output of a Gutenberg block in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to change the default HTML output of a Gutenberg block in WordPress 5.7. For example, the default output of a `core/Group` block with a paragraph inside is:

```html
<div class="wp-block-group">
    <div class="wp-block-group__inner-container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to output something like this:

```html
<table role="presentation" class="my-own-custom-class">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried using a custom filter on the `render_block_core/group` hook. But I seem to only be able to add content around what WordPress already outputs. Here’s an example:

```php
function my_group_block_wrapper( $block_content, $block ) {
    $content  = '<table role="presentation" class="my-own-custom-class"><tr><td>' . $block_content . '</td></tr></table>';
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'render_block_core/group', 'my_group_block_wrapper', 10, 2 );
```

And here’s what I get:

```html
<table role="presentation" class="my-own-custom-class">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="wp-block-group">
                <div class="wp-block-group__inner-container">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I get rid of the divs generated by WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually loop through blocks by retrieving them from the content using `parse_blocks()`.

> Parses blocks out of a content string.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/parse_blocks/

```
<?php
if ( ! empty( get_the_content() ) ) { //... check if the content is empty
    $blocks = parse_blocks( get_the_content() ); //... retrieve blocks from the content
    foreach ( $blocks as $block ) { //... loop through blocks
        echo wp_strip_all_tags( render_block( $block ) ); //... strip all html and render blocks
    };
};
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ideally, I would not want sub blocks to be filtered from their default HTML output. Would there be a way to do that (and if possible generically, so it can adapt to different type of blocks)?

Comment: I misunderstood at first. Well you can remove the `if`/`else` statements and it will apply to every block. I've edited. That's the most generic thing you can do. If the output is not suiting you then you need to target each block to "clean" them one by one". That's how Gutenberg works.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see how I can work around this approach.